# Checking if user's email address matches any existing email addresses in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, forgot-password

I have a form that requires a user to enter their email address in order to receive a password reset email. I'm trying to compare the email to existing emails in the database before sending the email; if the email doesn't exist, the script should not send the reset email. I've been reading posted questions/responses and Googling my brains out for hours, as well as altering the code to remove white space or tweak the syntax but nothing has rid me of this #1064 error message...'bouts ta give up...

The error I get is:
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@rocketmail.com' at line 1
SQL: SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE customer_email = user@rocketmail.com**

```
$sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE customer_email = ".$_POST['email'];
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db)."<br />SQL: $sql");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows < 1) {
$problem = TRUE;
$error_message .= '<p class="errorctr">Email was not found in our database.</p>';
}
```

Comment: also, your code is vulnerable to sql injection, please use parametrized query (using myqli prepare or PDO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enclose a string value in quotes, otherwise it will surely be a syntax error that you get. Your PHP syntax is fine, MySQL is not

```
$sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE customer_email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email'])."'";
```

Also later down in your code you have `mysql_num_rows`, which shuld be `mysqli_num_rows` like this

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string  According to that MAN page the description of that parameter is `Procedural style only: A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init() `

Comment: I will never in my life understand why PHP users are so inclined to number of rows.

Comment: BTW, such a freedom in addressing the nickname still triggered the notification. It's interesting thing to discover, thank you. Could be a later edit though

Comment: @Wil  There might have been a misunderstanding in interpretation of what YourCommonSense wanted to say. He is a respected member of society and trust me you will learn a lot from him if you continue to remain an active member of this forum. Although i'm no one to comment on this but if I were you I would just not let this argument build up. One can disagree but I believe there is no reason for a continuation to this argument. Cheers and Chill out. It was nothing personal against you in my opinion.

Comment: Noted. But for all the good he may offer, his presumptuousness is off-putting and discouraging. I showed more effort in my post than a good many of the posts, yet I merited a downvote because his previous answers on the subject weren't in stackoverflow's search results when I searched and read (for hours) prior to posting. That's _my_ fault?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of what you *really* need to try, it is [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdo):

```
$sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE customer_email = ?";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($_POST['email']));
$id  = $stm->fetchColumn();
if(!$id) {
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE customer_email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$email )."'";
   $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db)."<br />SQL: $sql");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        if(!$row['customer_email']){
         echo '<p class="errorctr">Email was not found in our database.</p>';
               }

      }
```